# Spring Security Core doesn't decrypt password

Tags: authentication, grails

I followed the example screencast by Peter Ledbrook on using the spring security core. I set the password on my user as follows:

```
    springSecurityService.encodePassword("password")
```

When I attempt to log in, it doesn't decrypt the password properly. If I change the app to not encrypt the password, it will log in perfectly.

I looked at the auto-generated Login controller and I am not seeing where it's doing the decryption of the password. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there something that I am missing to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no decryption of the password, because the encryption is not reversible. When you register your password is enrypted and stored in the DB. When you attempt to login the password entered is encrypted and compared against the (encrypted) password in the DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 1.2 the User domain class encrypts the password, so by using `springSecurityService.encodePassword` you're double-encoding. See the docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: This is highlighted (in underlined text) in the blog post that accompanies the aforementioned screencast http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/